# Checking if result was returned and assigning to variable

Tags: python, postgresql, error-handling, psycopg2

I'm using psycopg2. I find I do a lot of queries but sometimes no result is returned. How do I check for this? When I try to assign a value from the query to the result I get `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`. To fix this, instead of

```
cur.execute(...)
result = cur.fetchone()
myVar = result[0]
```

I now do

```
if result is not None:
    myVar = result[0]
else:
    myVar = None
```

so that the try/except TypeError will catch it when it is used latter on. Is there a better way to do this? This kind of sucks because now when I use the values to insert back to db it just aborts the transaction when it tries to insert `None`.

Answer (score 1):

`cur.fetchone()` returns `None` when the query produces no rows. You handle that OK by checking for `None`, however, you should also check for `None` in your insertion code.

If it is valid to insert `None` into a column `psycopg2` will covert `None` into SQL NULL when appropriate. You could do this:

```
cur.execute("select * from blah where id=%s", (id,))
result = cur.fetchone()
myVar = result[0] if result is not None else None

# insert
cur.execute("insert into blah values (%(id)s, %(name)s)", {'id':100, 'name': None})
cur.execute("select * from blah where id=%s and name is NULL", (100,))
result = cur.fetchone()
myVar = result[0]
print myVar
# outputs None
```

I'm not sure whether you are using them, but note that the use of parameterised queries helps with this, and it reduces your application's vulnerability to SQL injection attacks too.

Comment: `cur.execute("insert into blah values (%(id)s, %(name)s)", {'id':100, 'name': None})` could you explain? This is definitely different than what I do. Does this check for None? I was told not to use `%` for string substitution as it's old fashioned and `.format()` should be used instead.

Comment: This is simply an example of a parameterised query. Instead of creating the string directly by substituting variables into it with `%(name)s`, `%s`, or `format()`, placeholders are inserted into the query string and the values are passed as an argument to `execute()`. In this case I passed a dictionary to `execute()`, but you can also pass a tuple and use placeholder `%s`. The DB layer takes care of escaping and quoting so as to reduce the likelihood of an SQL injection. For normal string operations `format()` is now recommended over `%s` style substitution.